# How do I use XML prefixes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

> EDIT: I have now published my app: http://pastebin.com/PYAxaTHU

I was trying to make console-based application that returns my temperature.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;


namespace GetTemp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(downloadWebPage(
             "http://www.andrewmock.com/uploads/example.xml"
            ));

            XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            man.AddNamespace("aws", "www.aws.com/aws");

            XmlNode weather = doc.SelectSingleNode("aws:weather", man);
            Console.WriteLine(weather.InnerText);
            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the sample XML:

```
<aws:weather xmlns:aws="http://www.aws.com/aws">
   <aws:api version="2.0"/>
   <aws:WebURL>http://weather.weatherbug.com/WA/Kenmore-weather.html?ZCode=Z5546&Units=0&stat=BOTHL</aws:WebURL>
   <aws:InputLocationURL>http://weather.weatherbug.com/WA/Kenmore-weather.html?ZCode=Z5546&Units=0</aws:InputLocationURL>
   <aws:station requestedID="BOTHL" id="BOTHL" name="Moorlands ES" city="Kenmore" state=" WA" zipcode="98028" country="USA" latitude="47.7383346557617" longitude="-122.230278015137"/>
   <aws:current-condition icon="http://deskwx.weatherbug.com/images/Forecast/icons/cond024.gif">Mostly Cloudy</aws:current-condition>
   <aws:temp units="&deg;F">40.2</aws:temp>
   <aws:rain-today units=""">0</aws:rain-today>
   <aws:wind-speed units="mph">0</aws:wind-speed>
   <aws:wind-direction>WNW</aws:wind-direction>
   <aws:gust-speed units="mph">5</aws:gust-speed>
   <aws:gust-direction>NW</aws:gust-direction>
</aws:weather>
```

I'm just not sure how to use XML prefixes correctly here.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: What kind of error did you get? How do you know it isn't working? These will be relevant details to get help.

Comment: Short advice: Use XDocument, not XmlDocument.

Comment: And include the "http://" in the namespace string.

Comment: http:// has no value in a namespace string. Namespaces are, by design, opaque strings (strictly URIs); the most important characteristic is uniqueness. It's often convenient to base namespaces on DNS names, as then at least you know any collisions aren't your fault!. 
EDIT: Sorry Henk - now I see it. You are correct - the mismatch in namespace URIs is the problem, as noted by mark_s in his answer. So - yes - http:// does have value in a namespace URI - if it's part of the namespace URI you are trying to reference :-)

Comment: @DominicCronin : did you notice the ns in the sample?

Comment: Indeed Henk, I edited my comment once I realised what you were driving at.

Comment: Note also that there is no relation between the prefix you choose to use in your code and the prefix used by the XML document itself.  It would work just as well to say man.AddNamespace("foo", "...") and then doc.SelectSingleNode("foo:weather").  http://dannythorpe.com/2010/11/12/using-namespaces-with-linq-xpathselectelement/

Answer (score 12):

OK, so based on this XML from the example:

```
<aws:weather xmlns:aws="http://www.aws.com/aws">
   <aws:api version="2.0"/>
   <aws:WebURL>http://weather.weatherbug.com/WA/Kenmore-weather.html?ZCode=Z5546&Units=0&stat=BOTHL</aws:WebURL>
   <aws:InputLocationURL>http://weather.weatherbug.com/WA/Kenmore-weather.html?ZCode=Z5546&Units=0</aws:InputLocationURL>
   <aws:station requestedID="BOTHL" id="BOTHL" name="Moorlands ES" city="Kenmore" state=" WA" zipcode="98028" country="USA" latitude="47.7383346557617" longitude="-122.230278015137"/>
   <aws:current-condition icon="http://deskwx.weatherbug.com/images/Forecast/icons/cond024.gif">Mostly Cloudy</aws:current-condition>
   <aws:temp units="&deg;F">40.2</aws:temp>
   <aws:rain-today units=""">0</aws:rain-today>
   <aws:wind-speed units="mph">0</aws:wind-speed>
   <aws:wind-direction>WNW</aws:wind-direction>
   <aws:gust-speed units="mph">5</aws:gust-speed>
   <aws:gust-direction>NW</aws:gust-direction>
</aws:weather>
```

You're trying to read out which value?

What's wrong with your code is that your XML namespace is wrong:

You have:

```
XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
man.AddNamespace("aws", "www.aws.com/aws");
```

but the XML namespace is: `http://www.aws.com/aws`

so you should have:

```
 XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
 man.AddNamespace("aws", "http://www.aws.com/aws");
```

So to read out e.g. the temperature, use something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(downloadWebPage("http://www.andrewmock.com/uploads/9/1/0/7/9107466/example.xml"));

XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
man.AddNamespace("aws", "http://www.aws.com/aws");

XmlNode temps = doc.SelectSingleNode("/aws:weather/aws:temp", man);

string tempValue = temps.InnerText;
```

Gives you a value of `"40.2"` in `tempValue`

And as Henk Holtermann recommended in his comment - it would be even easier to read this with Linq-to-XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://www.andrewmock.com/uploads/9/1/0/7/9107466/example.xml");

XNamespace aws = "http://www.aws.com/aws";

var weatherNode = doc.Document.Descendants(aws + "weather");
var tempNode = weatherNode.Descendants(aws + "temp").FirstOrDefault();

string tempValue = tempNode.Value;
```

Of course, this doesn't include any error handling just yet (checking for things like the `weatherNode` being NULL and stuff like that) - but it gives you an idea.

Comment: Thanks!! I have finished my app